# Write a function that allocates an array of 100 chars in the heap in C

Tags: arrays, heap-memory

Write a function that allocates an
array of 100 chars in the heap, sets them to ’b’ if their index
is divisible by 9 and to ’1’ otherwise, and deallocates the heap
array.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please show your previous efforts and tell us which language you are using

Comment: I used C programming languiage

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, but I couldn't test it.

```c
void test() {
    char* arr = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if(i % 9 == 0) {
            arr[i] = 'b';
        } else {
            arr[i] = '1';
        }
    }
    free(arr);
}
```